# Remap $json1 keys and structure to fit $json2 keys and structure using PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, converters

I have 2 JSON arrays:

- $json1_array : From 3rd Party #1
- $json2_array : From 3rd Party #2

Despite the data itself being the same in each JSON file (housing property data: Bathrooms, bedrooms, description, images etc) $json1_array uses different $keys and has a different structure to $json2_array.

**I have found** many questions where people have tried to change the structure a single JSON array and change its keys, but this has always been using a single JSON array. **However** I would like $json1_array to be converted to match the structure of $json_array2.

**I have looked** into the array_merge which returned undesirable results such as placing $json1 $keys into $json2_array array which I do not want.

I have tried an approach of rewriting the keys from $json1 to fit $json2_array using something like this:

```
public function rewriteKeys($newKeyFormat, $newArr) 
{

$newKeyFormat = array(    
    'address1' => 'address',
    'address2' => 'address',
    'city' => 'city',
    'state' => 'state',
    'zip_code' => 'postal_code',
}
[Note: Could not get this to work]
```

Struggles occur when I try and re-write the convert address1, address2 to be just address. I would guess that in this part of the work I would need the array_merge function.

$json1_array (Snippet due to length):

```
{"data":[{
"id":32,
"last_update":"2016-08-31 15:06:13",
"address":{
    "address1":"Villa Chicca",
    "address2":null,
    "city":"LEZZENO",
    "state":"Province Of Como",
    "zip_code":"-",
    "country":"Italy",
"details":{
    "dwelling_name":"Villa Chicha",
    "dwelling_type":"Villa\/Cottage",
    "maximum_capacity":8,
    "base_capacity":8,
    "bedrooms":4,
    "bathrooms":3,
    "currency":"EUR"},
"urls":[{
    "type":"Main",
         "url":"www.google.com"},{
             "type":"Contact owner",
             "url":"www.google.com#contact-owner"},{
                 "type":"Contact",
                 "url":"www.google.com#contact-us"}],
"descriptions":{
    "dwelling_description":"This besuch as catering, cooking lessons and spa treatments.",
    "rate_description":null,
    "location_description":"The area aroAirport: 100 km",
    "capacity_info":null,
    "catering_services":"Servit can really make the difference.",
    "wedding_conference_info":null,
    "special_offers":null,
    "interior_grounds":"rThe Vable if required",
    "getting_there":null,
    "terms_and_conditions":"\r\n"},
"extras":["Maid servic","Chef\/Cook available",],
"amenities":["Wi-Fi"],
"photos":[
    {
    "order":0,
    "url":"www.google.com_1_.jpg?utm_source=feeds&utm_medium=feeds&utm_campaign=melt"
    }
    ,{
    "order":1,
    "url":"www.google.com?utm_source=feeds&utm_medium=feeds&utm_campaign=melt"
    },{
    "order":2,
    "url":"hwww.google.com?utm_source=feeds&utm_medium=feeds&utm_campaign=melt"},
    {
```

$json2_array (Snippet due to length):

```
"id": 0,
"host_id": 0,
"cleaning_time": 0,
"cleaning_time_min": 0,
"cleaning_fee": true,
"title": "string",
"size": 0,
"checkin": "string",
"checkout": "string",
"created_at": "string",
"updated_at": "string",
"deleted_at": "string",
"deactivated_at": "string",
"availability_updated_at": "string",
"rates_updated_at": "string",

"location": 
  "id": 0,
  "country_iso2": "string",
  "latitude": "string",
  "longitude": "string",
  "city": "string",
  "country_name": "string",
  "state_province": "string",
  "postal_code": "string",
  "address": "string",
  "timezone": "string"

,
"rate": 
  "version": 0,
  "daily_default": 0,
  "weekly_percentage_decrease": 0,
  "monthly_percentage_decrease": 0,
  "weekend_increase": 0,
  "minimum_stay": 0,
  "maximum_stay": 0,
  "extra_person_fee": 0,
  "extra_person_fee_trigger_amount": 0
,
"property_id": ,
"portal_title": 
  "attribute_name": "string",
  "translations": 

      "id": 0,
      "subject": "string",
      "content": "string",
      "language_id": 0,
      "container_id": 0,
      "container_type": "Listing",
      "attribute_name": "string"

  ],
  "id": 0,
  "subject": "string",
  "content": "string",
  "language_id": 0,
  "container_id": 0,
  "container_type": "Listing"
,
"description": 
  "attribute_name": "string",
  "translations": 

      "id": 0,
      "subject": "string",
      "content": "string",
      "language_id": 0,
      "container_id": 0,
      "container_type": "Listing",
      "attribute_name": "string"

  ],
  "id": 0,
  "subject": "string",
  "content": "string",
  "language_id": 0,
  "container_id": 0,
  "container_type": "Listing"
,
```

Looking at $json1_array we can see:

- Address -> address1
- address -> address2
- address -> city

However, looking at $json2_array:

- location -> address
- location -> city

Given that the clear complexity of what I am trying to achieve I would like to know if it is even possible? And of course, if it is possible how?

**Defined Question:** How convert the $keys and structure of a multidimensional json array to exactly match that of another json array taking into consideration $keys which may require merging.

**I expect to see $json1_array having the same structure as $json2_array.**

Thanks

Comment: Being a community website, you'd think that if a user wishes to mark something down, that they should at least provide reasoning as it doesn't exactly help me improve my question by seeing negative marking without reasoning.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it is probably due the the fact this is basically a request for someoen to write the code for you, and that is not what SO is for. We are most willing to help you fix some code that is not doing what you hoped, but we dont write it all for you.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ill leave those, just in case ;) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php .. Oh and by the way have you tried use stdClass ? it's really easy!

Comment: Cheers for the explanation Riggs - at least that is a little more useful. That said, I have been working on this project sine September, I am not a server side developer, certainly not an API developer so what I have produced to date is a learn as you go a long sort of approach, I am also quite pleased with what I have produced given my non-programming background.

Comment: Until earlier when I almost pulled my hair out, I had been retrieving json, converting to php, storing in SQL and then calling it as I require it / converting back to json. Given that I am getting and posting json, it seems more useful to store it. I just don't know enough about arrays to get going. Reading does not work for me (as I am a visual learner), working on projects does.

Comment: sorry @dehood Thanks for the links, I've seen stdClass but not tried it, will certainly have a look though - cheers for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array by iterating through the array you want to change. You can check for keys you want to change and specify a new key name.

**Disclaimer:** I am not a php developer so this is a really inefficient method. You should look into the `array_map` function to make this simpler and faster.

```
<?php

// Dummy data
$rawArray1 = array('Name' => 'Test 1', 'PropType' => 'Test', 'Address 1' => 'Long address', 'Address 2' => 'Longer part 2');

// Structure to match
$rawArray2 = array('Name' => 'Test 2', 'Type' => '', 'Address' => '');

$jsonArray1 = json_encode($rawArray1);
$jsonArray2 = json_encode($rawArray2);

// End dummy data

// Data request api 1
$obj1 = json_decode($jsonArray1, true);

// Data request api 2
$obj2 = json_decode($jsonArray2, true);

$newArr = array();

// Loop through the array you want to change
// We will create a new array specifying the names of the new keys we want
foreach($obj1 as $key => $value) {
    // Identify the key you want to change
    if ($key == 'Address 1' || $key == 'Address 2') {

      // Concatenate two keys 
      if (isset($newArr[ 'Address' ])) {
        $newArr[ 'Address' ] = $newArr[ 'Address' ] . $value;
      } else {
        $newArr[ 'Address' ] = $value;
      }
      continue;
  }

  // Simply change the name of the key
  if ($key == 'PropType') {
      $newArr['Type'] = $value;
      continue;
  }

  $newArr[ $key ] = $value;
}

var_dump($newArr);

// Encode to use
$data = json_encode($newArr);

?>
```

Comment: Cheers for giving me a hand Josh, I get what you are doing here so I think with a little editing, I should be able to use this. I am told by Sean (Forensic Sean) that I should be building this from the ground up and use Java / JS / AngularJS so I think that will have to be 2.0 xD Thanks again for your input mate.

Comment: Note: To others reading the comments, I have set this reply as the Answer because my question was asking if there was a way I could achieve my goal and what approach I should be using. Once I have found build my solution, I will update my initial post so that others with a similar goal can perhaps benefit from this question.